# setTimeout() method won't execute

Tags: javascript

I have written a script, but i want to limit execution time for some functions. I decided to try setTimeout() method, however it results in no time out when i execute the program, i.e. setTimeout() does not work.

setTimeout(rollDice(), 6000) is the line that executes instantly

Here is my code :

```
function rollDice() {
diceOne = Math.round(5 * Math.random() + 1);
diceTwo = Math.round(5 * Math.random() + 1);
}
function mainFunction() {
playerAI.playing = true;
playerOne.playing = true;
currentScore = 0;
playerAI.totalScore = 0;
playerOne.totalScore = 0;
while (playerAI.playing == true && playerOne.playing == true) {
    makeMove();
}
}
function makeMove() {
if (who == 0) {
    aiStrat();
    game();
}
else {
    var confirmAction = confirm("Kas soovite visata täringuid?");
    if (confirmAction) {
    decision = 1;
    }
    else {
    decision = -1;
    }
    game();
}
}
function game() {
if (decision == 1) {
    setTimeout(rollDice(), 6000); // <--- THIS GETS EXECUTED INSTANTLY
    if (diceOne != 1 && diceTwo != 1){
        currentScore += diceOne + diceTwo;
//and so on
```

Comment: diceOne and diceTwo are undefined.. Call it once before you set the timeout.. Geez ;(

Comment: they are defined, i just did not want to copy entire script

Comment: @Evald He means that they're not defined right after calling `setTimeout`, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code should look like this:

```
setTimeout(rollDice, 6000);
```

By adding the parentheses, you're calling the function and setting a timer for calling whatever that function returns. You'll want to pass the function object itself.

You can't immediately use `diceOne` and `diceTwo` after setting the timeout. You have to put that code in the timeout function as well, for example:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    rollDice();

    if (diceOne != 1 && diceTwo != 1){
        currentScore += diceOne + diceTwo;
    ...
}, 6000);
```

That's because the code after `setTimeout` will not wait before the timeout has finished.

Comment: if you wanted to pass parameters to rollDice, you could use setTimeout(function(){ rollDice(1); }, 6000); as well

Comment: it does not wait 6 seconds and gets executed immideately

Comment: @Evald The code you have after `setTimeout` should also be called within the timeout function. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, it actually does work the correct way, it was my mistake. diceOne and diceTwo do get new value after 6 seconds, i was mistaken by the confirm() function, that comes later and pops up immideately. I thought setTimeout() would stop the entire loop for 6 seconds at given line, but it goes on despite the timeOut for one function

Comment: @Evald Correct, when you call `setTimeout` or `setInterval`, all you're doing is scheduling some code to be run at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    rollDice()
}, 6000)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of Brackets when calling rollDice Function.

```
    setTimeout(rollDice, 6000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this:

setTimeout(function(){rollDice()}, 6000);